# How to populate matlab GUI edit texts with values from MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, matlab

I have created a table with 10 columns in matlab database toolbox. How do i retrieve the values and show them in matlab GUI? when I use the code below, I get Undefined function 'fetch' for input arguments of type 'double' error. Can anybody tell me what is wrong with my code?

```html
f = getappdata(0,'fvalue');

%Set preferences with setdbprefs.
setdbprefs('DataReturnFormat', 'cellarray');
setdbprefs('NullStringRead', 'null');


%Make connection to database. 
conn = database('marine_invertebrates', '', '');

%Read data from database.
curs = fetch(conn, sprintf(['SELECT  description.commonName'...
    ' , description.scientificName'...
    ' , description.kingdom'...
    ' , description.phylum'...
    ' , description.subphylum'...
    ' , description.class'...
    ' , description.order'...
    ' , description.family'...
    ' , description.genus'...
    ' , description.species'...
    ' FROM  marine_cbir.description WHERE description.imageID = "%s"'], num2str(f)));

curs = fetch(curs);
close(curs);

%Assign data to output variable
results = curs.Data;

commonName = set(handles.edit11,'String'); 
display (commonName);
scientificName = set(handles.edit1,'String');
display (scientificName);
kingdom = set(handles.edit2,'String');
display (kingdom);
phylum = set(handles.edit3,'String'); 
display (phylum);
subphylum = set(handles.edit4,'String');
display (subphylum);
class = set(handles.edit5,'String');
display (class);
order = set(handles.edit6,'String');
display (order);
family = set(handles.edit7,'String');
display (family );
genus = set(handles.edit8,'String');
display (genus);
species = set(handles.edit9,'String');
display (species );
```

Comment: The error is due to a wrong call to the function `fetch`; maybe in the first call `curs = fetch(conn,sprintf(...))` you mean to use `exec` instead? That's just a guess though. As for populating text boxes, you need to supply the actual string with the call to `set(handles.[...],'String','YourStringHere')`

Comment: In addition you might want to check if you have a valid connetion using *isconnection(conn)* before fetching the data. ALso as @Benoit_11 alredy pointed out, you should use the *exec* command first and then *fetch*. Ex: res = exec(conn, 'SQL QUERY'); res = fetch(res);

Comment: Thank you! I meant to use exec initially but I wasn't sure..thanks for the explanation..and yes, iv'e check using 'isconnection(conn)' and got value 1 so it's valid..one more question @Benoit_11: how do I pass the values from the database to 'set(handles.[...],'String','YourStringHere')'..as in instead of 'Your string here', I want the values to be from the database..how do I do that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Mhh sorry I don't know much about manipulating databases with Matlab :(